# Slick-слайдер: как изменить направление движения слайдов?

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

По умолчанию при autoplay: true слайды перемещаются справа налево. Как сделать движение слева направо?

В документации не нашёл: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ (или не разобрался? подскажите, кто сталкивался и знает, как сделать).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

установите свойство `rtl: true`, это есть в документации, и не забудьте блоку с элементами слайдера прописать атрибут `dir="rtl"`

https://jsfiddle.net/5ox31m2a/1201/

Comment: спасибо! (три четыре пять)